# How to avoid magic Gtk2 accel_key numbers?

Tags: perl, gtk, gtk2

I'm want an accelerator for a subroutine in my GTK application, using the `Gtk2` bindings for Perl. [`Gtk2::AccelGroup`](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Gtk2/AccelGroup.html)`->connect()` takes an `$accel_key` as argument, which seems to be an integer representing a key. Can `Gtk2` export constants or a function to use in place of this magic number?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Gtk2::Accelerator->parse()](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Gtk2/Accelerator.html#_accelerator_key_acc):

```
use Gtk2;
my ( $key, $mods ) = Gtk2::Accelerator->parse( '<control><alt>a' );
# $key is 97
# $mods is '[ control-mask mod1-mask ]'

my $ag = Gtk2::AccelGroup->new();
$ag->connect(
    Gtk2::Accelerator->parse( '<control><alt><a>' ),
    [qw/visible/], sub { say 'hi' }
);
```